# This puzzle is not solved yet. : Is this correct?

Tags: grammar

This puzzle is not solved yet by anyone. - Is this grammatically correct?

Comment: Yes, it is. A more idiomatic way of putting this would be "This puzzle remains unsolved."

Comment: Maybe the question is: should it be "is not solved yet" or "has not been solved yet".

Answer (score 5):

There is some questionable grammar in it.

The phrase *is not solved* treats *solved* as an adjective, and the phrase *solved ... by anyone* treats *solved* as a verb.

To have strictly correct grammar, you need to choose one or the other. So it should be *"This puzzle has not yet been solved by anyone,"* or *"This puzzle is not solved yet."*

Comment: Nice catch :) .

Comment: Maybe it is just me, but surely there is something not quite right in putting in 'yet' when we have already said that the puzzle is not solved. What does 'yet' add? It seems much more natural to say 'This puzzle has not yet been solved.'

Comment: @JeremyC: I agree that "is not yet solved" is indeed slightly better, but I wouldn't call putting "yet" at the end "unnatural" or "not quite right".